# Common events that will cancel a recurring alarm

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager, recurring, android-alarms

I was wondering what some common events were that would cancel a recurring alarm.  I am catching them so I can reset the alarm when needed.  What are some other common one's that I may not be handling?  Here is what I am currently handling:

- PACKAGE_REPLACED/CHANGED/REMOVED/DATA_CLEARED
- BOOT_COMPLETED